# C How to stop file from being overwritten

Tags: c, unix

Currently the the file gets created and overwritten. I am trying to get it so that if the file already exists it just exits the program. open must be used.

```
if ((dest = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644)) == -1) {
    printf("Error File %s exists", argv[2]);
    return 3; 
 }
```

Comment: `man perror`  Don't use prinft to write error messages.  It goes to the wrong stream, and it doesn't provide enough information.  (Not much more info will be available in this case, but generally `perror` is far more useful.)

Comment: Did you read the man page? Why not? What did you not understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `O_EXCL`:

> `O_EXCL` Ensure that this call creates the file: if this flag is
>   specified in conjunction with `O_CREAT`, **and pathname already exists,
>   then `open()` will fail**.